# Should I add multiple <location> elements for multiple pages in Web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, roles

I am using `Asp.Net/C#` ,I am using `Roles` based Authorization for access to many of my pages.Until now I have only two pages that are accessible to only Admin Role.For denying access to other roles I am using this in my Web.config file.

```
<location path="CreateAccount.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

This is for page1 , suppose in future I keep adding more pages that are only accessible to admin role , how do I manage that , should I add a `location` element per page or is there a way around.I know I can group them in a folder and then add a web.config file for that.Is this a better approach if I add many pages in future.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably go the other way - by default all pages are at the highest restriction level (possibly admin) and then whitelist ones that others can access. This means that if a page is added and config isn't updated no one who should not be able to see it will be able to.

As to how to achieve this: yes, having a web.config in a sub directory is probably the easiest way.

Comment: @richokelly do you mean grouping pages together and then adding a web.config file for them is a better approach.

Comment: @freebird In my experience yes - it reduces the overhead on developers and generally forces people into the 'pit of success' with regards to authorization.